# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, web

Recently I moved my website from localhost to a url domain, and now it keeps showing the errors above. The lines with problems are shown bellow. I think it's because the sintax that I used is from a more recent version of PHP, but I can't find any specific documentation for previous versions.

```
<?php echo explode(' ', $_SESSION['usuario_nome'])[0]; ?>

...

$fields_holder += [$name => $table_info[$i][$name]];
```

What is the equivalent of those lines of code to PHP < 5.4? 
Can anybody think of any other reason the code suddenly stopped working?

Sorry about my bad english...

Comment: So you wrote code for PHP5.4 at test with a view to implement the code in PHP5.3. What can you say except Woops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP5.3 does not support the short array syntax, it is new in PHP5.4

The syntax that should work in PHP < 5.4 and in PHP5.4 and > is

```
<?php 
    $t = explode(' ', $_SESSION['usuario_nome']); 
    echo $t[0];


    $fields_holder[] = array($name => $table_info[$i][$name]);
```

But I would guess that there is going to be more code that you are going to have to refactor if you have implemented this code on a server that is running PHP5.3

Answer (score 0):

In previous version you have to use *old* double-line syntax:

```
$array = explode(' ', $_SESSION['usuario_nome']);
echo $array[0];

$array = array( $name => $table_info[$i][$name] );
```

**The `+=` syntax with array is unsupported even in PHP > 5.3**